# Plot3D with restrictions through equalities and inequalities

Tags: plotting, regions

It all stems from this optimization problem:

```
NMaximize[{-((7/40 + c^2/7)/(1/10 + 2 c/7)) + ((1 - d/(14 (1/10 + 2 c/7))) Sqrt[1 + d^2])/d,
           d == ((1/10 + 2 c/7) (1 - d/(14 (1/10 + 2 c/7))))/(7/40 + 2/7 c (c/2 + d^2/(8 c))) && 
           7/2 >= 2 d >= 0 && d <= c <= 7/2 - d}, {c, d}]
```

> {0.40194, {c -> 1.04187, d -> 0.920991}}

Since I would like to visualize this graphically, I thought I'd write:

```
Plot3D[ConditionalExpression[
           -((7/40 + c^2/7)/(1/10 + 2 c/7)) + ((1 - d/(14 (1/10 + 2 c/7))) Sqrt[1 + d^2])/d, 
           d == ((1/10 + 2 c/7) (1 - d/(14 (1/10 + 2 c/7))))/(7/40 + 2/7 c (c/2 + d^2/(8 c))) && 
           7/2 >= 2 d >= 0 && d <= c <= 7/2 - d], {c, 0, 5}, {d, 0, 5}]
```

> [image]

It's evident that something has gone wrong but I don't understand what. Ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the restrict conditon

```
((1/10 + 2 c/7) (1 - d/(14 (1/10 + 2 c/7))))/(7/40 + 
     2/7 c (c/2 + d^2/(8 c))) - d==0
```

is the curve on `Plot3D`, so we need to use `Mesh` to draw it,that is we define `mesh[c,d]` and set `Mesh->{{0}}` to view  the curve `mesh[c,d]==0` on surface.

```
Clear[sol, reg, f, mesh]; sol = 
 NMaximize[{-((7/40 + c^2/7)/(1/10 + 2 c/7)) + ((1 - 
         d/(14 (1/10 + 2 c/7))) Sqrt[1 + d^2])/d, 
   d == ((1/10 + 2 c/7) (1 - d/(14 (1/10 + 2 c/7))))/(7/40 + 
        2/7 c (c/2 + d^2/(8 c))) && 7/2 >= 2 d >= 0 && 
    d <= c <= 7/2 - d}, {c, d}];
reg = ImplicitRegion[7/2 >= 2 d >= 0 && d <= c <= 7/2 - d, {c, d}];
f[c_, d_] = -((7/40 + c^2/7)/(1/10 + 2 c/7)) + ((1 - 
        d/(14 (1/10 + 2 c/7))) Sqrt[1 + d^2])/d;
mesh[c_, d_] = ((1/10 + 2 c/7) (1 - d/(14 (1/10 + 2 c/7))))/(7/40 + 
     2/7 c (c/2 + d^2/(8 c))) - d;
 Show[
 Plot3D[f[c, d], {c, d} ∈ reg, 
  MeshFunctions -> {mesh[#1, #2] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Green], 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.1], PlotPoints -> 40, MaxRecursion -> 2], 
 Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[5], Red, 
   Point[{c, d, f[c, d]}] /. sol[[2]]}], 
 ViewPoint -> {2.6, -0.55, 2.0}]
```

[image]